# Horizontal Progress bar with a gap in between the states

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am looking for a way to create the desired progress bar with a gap between the complete and incomplete state like this [image: Desired Image].
The gap should not be visible when progress is 0 or full. It should only be displayed when there is some progress but still incomplete. The Gap should be transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can design custom drawable for that that and use secondary progress with ***progress+1*** value.
Sharing code snippet for reference.

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_limit"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:maxHeight="10dip"
        android:minHeight="10dip"
        android:progress="50"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:secondaryProgress="52"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_limit" />
```

progress_limit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />

            <solid android:color="#bbbbbb"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners
                    android:radius="5dip" />
                <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners
                    android:radius="5dip" />
                <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```